# How to assign columns based on index while there is duplicated values in columns?

Tags: pandas

### data

```
    userid  test_label
0    a        nan
1    a        nan
2    b        nan
3    c        nan
4    d        nan
5    b        nan
```

The test_label value is null.

### Goal

The test_label value will be filled by the value of the index. If the values is odd, then the test_label will be 1 else 2. But if the test_label of userid is filled(a is 1), then test_label will be the same as below:

```
    userid  test_label
0    a        1
1    a        1
2    b        1
3    c        2
4    d        1
5    b        1
```

### Try

```
df['test_label']=np.where(df.index % 2,2,1)
```

I don't know how to keep the same value of the test_label if the value of userid is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add one more line of code that takes the `first` value of the group and applies to the others values in that group:

```
df['test_label']=np.where(df.index % 2,2,1)
df['test_label']=df.groupby('userid')['test_label'].transform('first')
df
Out[1]: 
  userid  test_label
0      a           1
1      a           1
2      b           1
3      c           2
4      d           1
5      b           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
df['test_label'] = df['userid'].map(df.drop_duplicates('userid')
                                      .assign(test_label=lambda x: x.index % 2 +1)
                                      .set_index('userid')
                                      ['test_label']
                                    )
```

Another option with `merge`:

```
df = (df.drop('test_label', axis=1)
   .merge(df.drop_duplicates('userid')
            .assign(test_label=lambda x: x.index % 2 + 1),
          on='userid')
)
```

Output:

```
  userid  test_label
0      a           1
1      a           1
2      b           1
3      c           2
4      d           1
5      b           1
```